# CakePHP Saving Data to Multiple Tables

Tags: cakephp

I'm using CakePHP 3 and have a registration form where in short you can set your username, password, email, but also some member stats (like weight, height, etc.)

Because I want the user to continually update their stats, I felt it better to include that in it's own table with a foreign key.

My challenge is creating the user in the `members` database, getting that `id` and inserting the rest of the data in the `member_stats` database and setting the `member_id` foreign key all within the CakePHP 3 framework.

So in particular I need to #1 use different models within the registration controller, and #2 bifurcate the data from one form into `member` and `member_stats` data, and use the `id` of members to populate to foreign key.

Comment: This is well covered in [the manual](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-with-associations) as well as having been answered here MANY times before. Check those resources, make an attempt, and if you can't get it to work, then share some code and explain what's not working about what you have so far.

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks for the insanely passive aggressive reply, it's very helpful.

Comment: Getting snarky with people who volunteer their time to help others is very helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

Cakephp smart enough to understand the relation from html form in Template.

## Relation part :

So when we have User table and UserDetails table and they both related like
Userdetails belong to User mean each Userdetails belong to one user and each user hasOne Details .

## Insert into both table from user add from

when you want to insert into UserDetails fro your registration form in your case is `Users/add.ctp`

inside `echo $this->Form->create($user);`

put your `UserDetails` input but the name is different for example if you have `weight` in `UserDetails` You can write something like
`echo $this->Form->control('userdetails.weight');` 
Note that `userdetails` is the second table name which is related to user .

## User Controller

in your add action you don't need to change any thing